# How to group items in a list by their first letter in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox, windows-phone-7

I have a ListBox to which I bound a sorted list of strings. I would like to display the list with dividers (headers) that announce the new letter - something like the 'Contacts' list on the iPhone.

Does anybody know how to achieve this goal? Perhaps using ListBox is not the right idea.

I am doing this with VS Express 2010 for Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't speak for silverlight, but the general .NET Practice would be as follows:

```
var groupings = mySortedString.GroupBy(x => x.Substring(0,1));
```

This makes an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>>` you then would bind this list to your listbox.

From here you'd have to come up with the XAML to represent it how you'd like, but this would group all your items.

Note: `IGrouping<,>` implements `IEnumerable<>` so you can enumerate off it for it's items.

Comment: Thank you, Aren. I will try this shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You might find some inspiration in [Erik Klimczak's implementation of a jump list control](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/windows_phone_7/archive/2010/06/24/that-s-a-huge-list-wp7-jump-list.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A jump list is now available in the November release of the Windows Phone Toolkit.

Details here. Refer **LongListSelector**.

[Mo controls, mo controls, mo controls... [Announcing the second release of the Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit!] - Delay's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/delay/mo-controls-mo-controls-mo-controls-announcing-the-second-release-of-the-silverlight-for-windows-phone-toolkit)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SilverLight WP7 Toolkit's LongListSelector to do this. It can be confusing getting your head round how it works...I know I certainly did! 
So I have just put up a blog on how to create a nested Group suitable for this. However if you just a straight forward list with no group short-cut linking, then you can just bind to a normal collection and use as a straight list.

http://nicholasrogoff.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/creating-an-easy-grouped-observablecollection-for-the-longlistselector/