# WP7 ListBox Grouping

Tags: listbox, windows-phone-7, grouping

Is there any in-built grouping for ListBoxes or another UI control?  I would like to have a list but have some form of grouping or sections applied to the list. As shown below:

```
heading one
     list item one
     list item two
heading two
     list item one
     list item two
     list item three
     list item four
```

Is there anything available for such purpose without building something from scratch?  I don't wish to mix a match multiple ListBoxes, rather I would prefer a solution where this was handled at the data binding level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look at the "Long List Selector" in the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034)

Its a control that looks+behaves just like the grouping behavior in contacts/etc on the phone.

[image: example image]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize there was a Nov. release of those tools.

Answer (score 6):

LongListSelector comes to mind.

[Using LongListSelector without LINQ - Andy Pennell's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andypennell/using-longlistselector-without-linq?wa=wsignin1.0)

[WP7 LongListSelector in depth | Part1: Visual structure and API | WindowsPhoneGeek](https://web.archive.org/web/20130118013503/http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api)

[WP7 LongListSelector in depth | Part2: Data binding scenarios | WindowsPhoneGeek](https://web.archive.org/web/20130118012859/http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios)

Alternatively, you could look into applying either of these grouping implementations to the phone's listbox.

[Confessions of a ListBox groupie [Using IValueConverter to create a grouped list of items simply and flexibly] - Delay's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/delay/confessions-of-a-listbox-groupie-using-ivalueconverter-to-create-a-grouped-list-of-items-simply-and-flexibly?wa=wsignin1.0)

[How to group items in a list by their first letter in Silverlight? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152540/how-to-group-items-in-a-list-by-their-first-letter-in-silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting the different lists in different items in a pivot?

Comment: No, I already have 4-5 pivot items.  It wouldn't really fit with the design of the app.  Thanks for the suggestion.